# Will the two elements in $S_n$ have the same cycle structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $a,b\in G$ such that $o(a)=o(b)$.

Since any group $G$ is isomorphic to a  subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$ then there exists a monomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$ .

Let the elements be mapped to $a_1,b_1$.

> Question:Will $a_1,b_1$ have the same cycle structure?

Now $a_1,b_1$ can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles $a_1=\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots \sigma_n;b_1=\rho_1\rho_2\dots \rho_m$.
Also $o(a_1)=o(b_1)$.

**EDIT**: The original question was :

> > If $a,b\in G$ be such that $o(a)=o(b)$ then does there exist a group $H$ containing $G$ such that $a,b$ are conjugate in $H$.
>
> I took $H=S_n$ and we know that two elements are conjugate in $S_n\iff$ they have the same cycle structure.

Is the original question false then?

Comment: If you could find a counterexample within a symmetric group, that would be enough (since you can map it to itself).

Comment: @pjs36;I have made some edits to the question.Will you please check that?

Comment: This is a completely different question from the original.

Comment: This question is "will they always have the same cycle structure?" And the original is "can you always choose the homomorphism so that they have the same cycle structure?"

Comment: The question is not false.  A solution runs along the lines of: write $ G $ as a presentation: $ G = \langle \{g_k\}_{k\in K} : \{r_j\}_{j\in J} \rangle $.  Then consider $ H = \langle \{g_k\}_{k\in K}, t : \{r_j\}_{j\in J}, tat^{-1}=b\rangle $.  Now, *a priori*, if $ \mathcal{o}(a) = n $, then any conjugate of $ a $ also has order $ n $.  So, if $ X $ is the normal closure of $ \{tat^{-1}\} $, then $ X \cap G = \{e\} $.  Thus, $ G \leq H $.  Obviously, you will need to elaborate more on why the normal closure is of that form.

Comment: Regarding the updated question, why doesn't the previous counterexample work again? Just make inclusion your embedding.

Answer (score 2):

Taking $G=S_n$ itself, your question boils down to asking whether two elements in $S_n$ with the same order have the same cycle structure. This is, of course, not true: Take
$$
n=4, \sigma = (12), \tau = (12)(34)
$$

Comment: I have made some edits to the question.Will you please check that?